# Getting error "pipeline element 3 is not an object error", while trying to find & update using aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using `node js mongodb driver` & trying to update an `object array` inside an object array in a document.

The **schema** of the document collection is this :

[image]

**What I Want :**

For collection with `order no = 1 & items.qty=2 & tax rate = 25`,  update the `tax to "cst" & taxratetype to "flat"`.

**What I Tried :**

```
db.OrderInfo.aggregate(
    {$match:{"orderno":"1"}},
    {$unwind:'$items'},
    { $match: { 'items.qty' : 2} 
 },function(err,result1){
    if(err){
    throw(err);
   }else{
   indexes = result1[0].items.taxes.map(function(obj, index) {
      if(obj.taxrate == 25) {
      return index;
   }
   }).filter(isFinite);

var updateData = {};
updateData["items.$.taxes."+indexes[0]+".tax"]="cst";
updateData["items.$.taxes."+indexes[0]+".taxratetype"]="flat";


db.OrderInfo.update({ "orderno":"1",'items.qty': 2,'items.taxes.taxrate': 25 },{$set: updateData },function(err,result2){
console.log(result2);
});

}
});
```

---

Currently I am using **db.eval** to run this script from node but later will change it once I accomplish the same.

**Getting this Error :**

> {"name":"MongoError","message":"Error: command failed: {\n\t\"ok\" :
>   0,\n\t\"errmsg\" : \"pipeline element 3 is not an
>   object\",\n\t\"code\" : 15942\n} : aggregate failed
>   :\n_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13\ndoassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14\nassert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:267:5\nDBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5\n_funcs1@:1:31\n","ok":0,"errmsg":"Error:
>   command failed: {\n\t\"ok\" : 0,\n\t\"errmsg\" : \"pipeline element 3
>   is not an object\",\n\t\"code\" : 15942\n} : aggregate failed
>   :\n_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13\ndoassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14\nassert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:267:5\nDBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5\n_funcs1@:1:31\n","code":139}

I know from this issue https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831
that I cannot use a direct update command & hence trying this workaround.
Any other approach for such updates is also fine with me.

**EDIT :**
As per answer given by @titi23, I had tried using [] also inside function. 
It did not gave me any error but, my values also did not get updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems in the query :

1) You are missing `[]` in the `aggregate` query.

2) The update method does not need the tax rate clause. It will find the nested document & the index from aggregate would serve the purpose in update.

Refer [aggregate-definition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) for more info on how to use it.

> Syntax - db.collection.aggregate(pipeline, options)
>
> `pipeline` - array - A sequence of data aggregation operations or stages.

Try the following:-

```
db.OrderInfo.aggregate([
{$match:{"orderno":"1"}},
{$unwind:'$items'},
{ $match: { 'items.qty' : 2} }]).toArray(
function(err,result1){
if(err){
    throw(err);
}
else{
   console.log(result[0]); //See is there any record here
   indexes = result1[0].items.taxes.map(function(obj, index) {
  if(obj.taxrate == 25) {
  return index;
  }
 }).filter(isFinite);

var updateData = {};
updateData["items.$.taxes."+indexes[0]+".tax"]="cst";
updateData["items.$.taxes."+indexes[0]+".taxratetype"]="flat";


 db.OrderInfo.update({ "orderno":"1",'items.qty': 2}, /*Remove the tax rate clause from here..*/
      {$set: updateData },function(err,result2){
        console.log(result2);
    });
  }
});
```

It should not throw the error.

**EDIT:-** Do `toArray()` with the aggregate, see if it helps. Updated the query already.

Comment: I had tried this also, it did not gave me any error but it did not update the values..

Comment: Try `{ '$items.qty' : 2}` instead of using `{ 'items.qty' : 2}`. Let me know if it works

Comment: it gives error : BadValue: unknown top level operator: $items

Comment: Edit your question with this requirement. This answer is for your initial question. Let me check what I can help you with.

Comment: Can you run the aggregate query, that I have updated and tell me, if it finding any record or not? Also I have added console. Let me know if the console is giving any record or not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out. I found the error.  it is the third where clause in update which is not giving a record

Comment: Okay. Glad to help you. Can you edit my answer with the solution you got, so that someone can get help in future.